# Bing Maps on Windows Store Apps (C#/XAML) display popup when pushpin tapped

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, bing, bing-maps

I'm using **Bing Maps** in my Windows Store app, I display some pushpins with some locations on it.

What I want to do is when the user taps on a pushpin, a popup appears with some info related to the location of that push pin. something similar to the popup when the user taps on my location in Microsoft maps application

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, you can use the `Tapped` event of your *Pushpin* to trigger a popup then use a `MapLayer.SetPosition` to position your popup see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846488.aspx

Like this

```
currentLocationPushpin.Tapped += Current_location_pushpin_tapped;
```

then

```
void Current_location_pushpin_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MapLayer.SetPosition(placesAroundYou,location);
  MapLayer.SetPositionAnchor(placesAroundYou, new Point(-200, 40));
  BingMap.Children.Add(_mapLayer);
}
```

Try using a **Popup** control or fake one like this

You can either use a *Popup control* (see [MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150602.aspx)) or toggle visibility of a **Border** element to fake a *Popup* using `Visibility="Collapsed"`, try this

```
<Border Background="#FFC3C2BF" Opacity="50" Margin="38,0,0,376" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="50" Width="126" Height="auto">
    <TextBlock x:Name="PushpinText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Padding="10,10,10,10" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already know this, the question is how to create the popup and display it on tapping ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used a popup that takes a border control as it's child